Possible bug with the table markdown
I've posted this question on Stack Overflow and I've added a table - using the markdown notation.
While in edit mode, the table is rendered correctly, once pressed the save button, the table misses its rendering.
Edit mode:

Public view:

Does someone has this same behaviour?

It looks like the --------- in the header messed with the rendering, as that gets translated to <hr>. The duplicate target is incorrect.

@Cerbrus I'm not sure what you mean.  There's no horizontal rule visible in either the screenshots or the rendered output of revision 1 of the question, and the source of that page does not contain the string <hr>.  Further, adding a single newline to the source of revision 1 results in the intended rendering, which is what the duplicate target describes.
